# Render nested array of Hashmaps with the usage of "@select" in .dust file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gruntjs, dust.js

I have JSON object containing the array of Hashmaps as:

```
{   "someparentkey": {
        "arraykey": [
            {
                "uniquekey": "key1",
                "content": "param1"
            },
            {
                "uniquekey": "key2",
                "content": "param2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Based on each value of `"uniquekey"`, I want to render the separate dust template with value of `"content"` passed to the imported dust template.

This is what my base template looks like right now:

```
{#someparentkey}
    {#arraykey}
        {@select key={uniquekey} }
            {@eq value="key1"}{>"path/to/dust1" param={content} /}{/eq}
            {@eq value="key2"}{>"path/to/dust2" param={content} /}{/eq}
            {@default}<!-- Invalid script tag {key} in configuration -->{/default}
        {/select}
    {/arraykey}
{/someparentkey}
```

And my imported templates ("path/to/dust1.dust" and "path/to/dust1.dust") are like:

```
<span>{param}</span>
```

But while doing the *"grunt build"* of the dust file, I am getting the error as:

> SyntaxError: Expected end tag for arraykey but it was not found. At line : 3, column : 9
> Blockquote
>
> Warning: Dust.js failed to compile template "path/to/my/base-dust".

**Questions:**

1. What's the issue in my current template code?
2. And is there any better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the template which I finally ended up using and it worked for me:

```
{#someparentkey.arraykey}
    {@select key=uniquekey }
        {@eq value="key1"}{>"path/to/dust1" param=content /}{/eq}
        {@eq value="key2"}{>"path/to/dust2" param=content /}{/eq}
        {@default}<!-- Invalid script tag {key} in configuration -->{/default}
    {/select}
{/someparentkey.arraykey}
```